# SQL - Compare speed of query execution

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, performance, time, execution-time

I have to insert 100,000 records into a table at one time.

I wrote two methods for it.

One is to Loop through 100,000 values from **VB.net** and insert them **one by one**.

The other is to send a **datatable** as a **parameter** from VB.net into the **stored procedure** in SQL

I should write a report about the difference of performances between the two. How do I get the exact time both took to be executed?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: print the start time and end time for each approach. You will know which one runs with good performance.

Comment: @chinna_82 I did,I printed the time on both start and end on VB.net. it showed that both tasks started and finished in the same second. Not too accurate....

Comment: that two methods....are those same program or 2 diffrerent program

Comment: @chinna_82 Same program

Comment: You could use the System.Timer.Stopwatch to time your results more accurately

Answer (score 0):

You will need to print or insert into another table the current time at the start and at the end. For this you can use `GETDATE()`.

On a side note, if you need to copy row from one table to another, I would consider using [SQLBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx). This allows you to efficiently bulk load a SQL Server table with data from another source.